# Multiple headers, how to use function on Object

Tags: c++, object, methods, header, typedef

How do I access a variable or typedef in a header from a method? It seems that the typedef isn't global even though I included the header file, why?

I have the following situation:

## Snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H
#include <utility>

class Snake {
public: 
    Snake(int difficulty, int posX, int posY) : difficulty(difficulty) {
        position.first = posX;
        position.second = posY;
    }
    inline std::pair<int,int> const getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

private: 
typedef std::pair<int, int> Point;
    Point position;
};

#endif // !Snake.h
```

## Movement.cpp

```
#include "Movement.h"
#include "Snake.h"

Snake moveDown() {

    Point dummy = SnakeObject.getPosition();
    return .....;
}
```

Now obviously this doesn't compile since there is stuff missing, but the compiler fails to recognize the Point type in the Movement.cpp file.
Also, do I need a Snake pointer in the Movement.h so I can use the snake object to call getPosition?

I'm sorry for the vague description, also your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look at which scope you defined your `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

`Point` is declared as a `private` class member, as such it is not accessible to non-class members.

Either make it a `public` class member, use the underlying `std::pair` type instead (like the declared return type of the method actually specifies), or assign the return value to an `auto`.

Comment: Even if you make it `public` you won't be able to access it like you do now. You will need proper type name `Snake::Point dummy = `.

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit clearer now. Does that mean that a private typedef only counts for the according .cpp file?

Also, is there any possibility that a public typedef could be changed?